# How do you enable the colors from the Debug package in PM2 logs?

Tags: node.js, pm2

I'm using the [Debug](https://www.npmjs.com/package/debug) package to produce logs, and I'm also using [PM2](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pm2) to start my app. When running `pm2 logs`, it does not show the default colors that are normally produced with the Debug logs when running the app using the `node` cli.

This is what is shown when using pm2 to output the logs:

[image: pm2 log output]

This is what is shown when using `node` to start the app:

[image: debug log output]

How can I view the logs through PM2 in the same output as when running the app with the `node` cli?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the environment variable `DEBUG_COLORS=true`. Then view the pm2 logs by running `pm2 logs --raw`.

As a side note, Debug will stream logs to stderr by default. If you want to use stdout instead, set `DEBUG_FD=1`.